# Замена курсора формы из ресурсов

Tags: c#

Как изменить стандартный курсор на свой? 
Например я закинул в ресурсы файл:

**MySOrce.cur** - это сам курсор.

Использовал много способов, но никак не получается применить именно из ресурсов!

В самом ресурсе файл именуется без .cur 
То есть просто название **MySOrce**

Использовал такой метод:

Класс:

```
class NewCursorAPI
{
    public static Cursor LoadCustomCursor(string path)
    {
        IntPtr hCurs = LoadCursorFromFile(path);
        if (hCurs == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
        var curs = new Cursor(hCurs);
        // Note: force the cursor to own the handle so it gets released properly
        var fi = typeof(Cursor).GetField("ownHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        fi.SetValue(curs, true);
        return curs;
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string path);
}
```

Затем использую:

```
 public FormLoader()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Cursor = NewCursorAPI.LoadCustomCursor(@"c:\windows\cursors\aero_busy.ani");
        }
```

Но курсор появляется только если сам файл лежит в где-нибудь в папке на самом компьютере, а нужно сделать чтобы запускал из ресурсов!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел что-то похожее вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897274/c-how-to-load-cursor-from-resource-file)

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(String str);

public static Cursor LoadCursorFromResource(string resourceName)
{         
     Stream cursorStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);        

     // Write a temp file here with the data in cursorStream

     Cursor result = new Cursor(LoadCursorFromFile(tempFile));
     File.Delete(tempFile);

     return result.
}
```

Фокус в том, что ты выгружаешь курсор из ресурсов в темповую директорию, а затем после загрузки удаляешь файл.

А что бы заменить курсор нужно сделать вот это:

```
Cursors.Current = LoadCursorFromResource("My.Namespace.Filename");
```

Comment: @ArteS, типа предлагается самому реализовать эту выгрузку. Ты можешь хоть в папку с программой это осуществить.